# JavaScript's `insertAdjacentHTML()` : What are "corruption of elements" & "serialization" in this context?

Tags: javascript, html, serialization

I'm trying to understand the `Element.insertAdjacentHTML()` method in JavaScript.

I have started with the MDN-article: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

The usage is clear to me.

But what I don't understand is this paragraph:

> *It does not reparse the element it is being used on and thus it does not **corrupt** the existing elements inside the element. This, and avoiding the extra step of **serialization** make it much faster than direct innerHTML manipulation.*

What is meant here with "... corrupt the existing elements ..."?

And what is meant with "serialization"??

I know serialization from Java. When objects are transformed to strings for to be stored in a file.

But here it is the reverse way: An object is created from a string.

So what "extra step" is shall be avoided here?